# Is it possible to securely delete a repository from Github

Tags: git, github

I have Github repository that I would like to delete securely (as in sdelete or shred).  Is that possible?  Is there a way to do this for Git remotes in general?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it without a access to the remote server itself.

Regarding GitHub, for instance, you would have to make a request by email to them (but without absolute guarantee that the shred has been done).

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can do it, how can you guarantee that the server doesn't have backups?

In other words, if you want to remove any existence of your git repository the answer is: **NO, you can't**. What if someone already cloned it? They can push it back to github...

This is applicable to any data posted online, be it a repository or any other information. Once it's online you can never be sure if someone already got it or not.

Comment: Thanks.  Good point.  In this case, it's a private repository, so I'm not too concerned about it having been cloned.